# Start list over when it's out of range

Tags: python, arrays

```
import time
from random import *
import random

rand = random.uniform(0.1,1)

letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]


run = input("Start? > ")
mins = 0

if run == "start":

    while mins != 60:

        print (">", letters[mins])

        time.sleep(rand)

        mins += 1
```

I want the the list to start over and over until "mins" has reached 60.

Comment: We aren't here to judge you by the way ! we are here to solve your problem , don't judge us!

Comment: what error do you get ? I mean what type of help we can provide to you ?

Comment: let me judge this line: `letters = [ a => z ]`: just do `letters = [chr(x+ord('a')) for x in range(26)]`

Comment: @orvi 
"IndexError: list index out of range"
This is the Error I get.
The program prints every letter until it reached "z", I want it to loop over until "mins" 60 is reached :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution could be to try changing your index to this:

```
print (">", letters[mins%len(letters)])
```

The modulo `%` function returns the remainder of the division operation. So in this case, once mins is greater than the length of the list, it 'starts over' at index 0.

Comment: Don't we `-1` after the find the actual length of letters?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `itertools.cycle`.

> [`itertools.cycle(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)
>
> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the saved copy. Repeats indefinitely.

And instead of typing out all (lowercase) letters of the alphabet you could use the string constant [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase).

```
import time
from itertools import cycle
from random import uniform
from string import ascii_lowercase

rand = uniform(0.1, 1) 
run = input("Start? > ")

if run == "start":
    for letter, _ in zip(cycle(ascii_lowercase), range(60)):
        print(">", letter)
        time.sleep(rand)
```